# How do you count user visits using C# & the default SQL Membership Provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm looking for a way to determine the most active users on my ASP.net application.  I could count logins by looking at the "LastLoginDate" of the aspnet_Membership table and compare this to the current date on each user login.  But this will be inaccurate if your most active users use the 'remember me' feature implemented with cookies.

What is the best way to count visits which would be more accurate, for instance by tracking Sessions instead of logins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the user logs in using a stored cookie the last login date will be updated.

Comment: Ok, assuming this to be true what is the most efficient way to check for this?  Maybe the "Page_Init" of a BasePage class which inherits from Page and from which all other pages descend?

Comment: So by putting logging code in the Session_Start, is there then any purpose for doing a LastLoginDate comparison, or is the event reliable enough to accept that this is truly a new session?

Comment: well... it depends what you want to count... i.e. if same person visits twice on the same day does it count as 2 visits or one? the event itself is as reliable as any, you just need to clearly define your logic...